Is it possible for a user to change an elevated account's password? (Windows)
We have a (windows server) machine that we rdp into, we don't want to allow connecting over rdp as an admin, but we want to have access to admin on the machine.
So, we have an admin account for each user, after they've connected, they can elevate themselves when needed using their mirrored admin account.
Is there any way for users to set the passwords for their mirrored admin account (over rdp)?
edit: I am not sure how to clarify, the boss doesn't want users (user accounts) with administrator permissions to be able to connect via RDP,
but the people (users) need administrator access, so each user that needs admin access have another user (user account) that is in the administrators group. This account can be used when the person needs administrator access. I was wondering if there is a way for the person to change their own administrator user's password....
anyways, the answer was me being an imbecile, they can just run as admin, Computer Management...

Are the admin accounts local accounts or domain accounts? Also, I believe your title is misleading. The answer to the question you ask in the title is "no", because a user account does not have access to another user account's password. How familiar are you with password change processes?

Yes, it is possible. Not just to change their password, but any password.
An admin has many rights.
All they need to do is start a command prompt as admin, and from there use net user to change their or someone elses password.
They could even make themselves an admin if they wanted (and know how).
Keep in mind, if the admin rights are local admin only, then their admin access is limited to that machine. If the users are domain users, this trick is not possible. If they are domain admin accounts, then they can do anything everywhere.

Your question lacks a lot of detail and context, but making several assumptions, I think I can answer your question. If this does not answer your question, please EDIT your question and clarify it.
Any user can access the Change Password prompt using CTRL-ALT-DEL over RDP. You would need to use the Send Keys function to send these keys to the target.
Once in the Change Password dialog, the password can be changed for any account the user has the current password to. This is a normal and standard thing on Windows, local or remote.
Just replace the username at the top of the dialog with the username the user wishes to change the password for, then enter the old password for the account they are changing the password for, and a new password.

Actually, when using RDP, its CTRL-ALT-END. The DEL still does it locally, even when connected over RDP.

Some RD clients have a Send Keys function too.

Yeah, they just send the CTRL-ALT-END, and call it CTRL-ALT-DEL.
